# Bean Validation on JAX-RS doesn't block an invalid request

Tags: java, jax-rs, bean-validation

I have a simple JAX-RS service, annotated with JSR-303 annotations:

```
@Path("/settings")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@ValidateRequest
public interface SettingsRestService {

    @POST
    SettingsResponse saveSetting (@Valid @NotNull Setting setting);
}
```

My `Settings` class:

```
public class Setting {

    @NotNull(message = "Field key must exist.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\w]+$", 
        message = "Field key must only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores.")
    private String key;

    @NotNull(message = "Field value must exist.")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "The value of the setting must be at least 1 character.")
    private String value;

    ...
}
```

When I send the following JSON object to my endpoint:

```
{
    "key": "aKey+",
    "value": "aValue"
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
    exception: null
    fieldViolations: [0]
    propertyViolations: [0]
    classViolations: [0]
    parameterViolations: [1]
      0: {
           constraintType: "PARAMETER"
           path: "SettingsRestService#saveSetting(arg0).key"
           message: "Field key must only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores."
           value: "aKey+"
         }-
      -
    returnValueViolations: [0]
}
```

Even though the validation works, the request still goes through the service and gets processed by the rest of the application.

Any ideas why this doesn't get blocked? Do I need additional configuration to process the validation?

The WAR is deployed on JBoss 6.3.3.GA and we're using Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-1 and resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.

Comment: Show the stacktrace.

Comment: I don't see anything in my logs. Any other ideas?

Comment: I can't see a reason for this behavior: *the request still goes through the service and gets processed by the rest of the application*.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is connected to a similar problem we had. It seems that our version of JBoss comes bundled with a buggy version of hibernate-validator. We had some problems before, where they validations didn't even trigger. But this time, the validations seem to trigger, just not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that in our case, an interceptor was 'hiding' the exception thrown from resteasy. I haven't found the 'why' yet, but if I have an update I'll let you know.